# how to take data to another class

Tags: java, arraylist

overhere i have made a program that can add a new object from variables that i put in. however the method i use to add the object to an array is from another class and if i call this method it won't be saved in the array. do i make an mistake or anything?

```
public class Programma extends Straat {

    public void ScriptAdresRijtjeshuis() {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("voer hier de straatnaam, huisnummer, verdieping, \n" +
                    "postcode, stad en oppervlakte in: ");
            String straat = in.nextLine();
            Integer nr = in.nextInt();
            Integer verdiepingen = in.nextInt();
            in.nextLine();
            String post = in.nextLine();
            String stad = in.nextLine();
            Integer massa = in.nextInt();
            addWoning(new Rijtjeshuis(straat, nr, verdiepingen, post, stad, massa));
    }
}
```

```
public class Straat {

    protected ArrayList<Woning> woningen;

    public Straat() {
        this.woningen = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addWoning(Woning woning) {
        this.woningen.add(woning);
    }

    public void zieStraat() {
        for (Woning woning: this.woningen) {
            System.out.println(woning.show());
        }
    }

    public void zoekAdres() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("voer hier de straat in waar u naar zoekt: ");
        String zoek = scanner.nextLine();
        String result = "";
        for (Integer i = 0; i < this.woningen.size(); i++) {
            result = this.woningen.get(i).show();
            if (result.contains(zoek))
                System.out.println(this.woningen.get(i).show());
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public abstract class Woning {
    protected String postcode;
    protected String straatnaam;
    protected Integer huisnummer;
    protected String stad;
    protected Integer oppervlakte;


    public Woning(String straatnaam, Integer huisnummer, String postcode, String stad, Integer oppervlakte) {
        this.straatnaam = straatnaam;
        this.huisnummer = huisnummer;
        this.postcode = postcode;
        this.stad = stad;
        this.oppervlakte = oppervlakte;

    }

    public abstract String show();
```

Comment: It seems you're doing it correctly. For me the most suspicious part is the code that you match the objects.

Could you please add implementation of Woningen class?

Comment: `addWoning` takes a `Woning` instance as an argument.  You're passing a new `Rijtjeshuis`; is `Rijtjeshuis` a sub-class of `Woning`?

Comment: yes, it is a subclass of woning

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do here, but it doesn't seem you want to extend `Programma` from `Straat`.
Rather, maybe create an instance of Straat (new Straat) in `Programma`, this way you initialize your `Woning` Arraylist. Doing so you add the `Woning` objects by accessing the `addWoning` method from your `Straat` class.

Something like:

```
public class Programma {
Straat straat = new Straat();
public void ScriptAdresRijtjeshuis() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("voer hier de straatnaam, huisnummer, verdieping, \n" +
                "postcode, stad en oppervlakte in: ");
        String straat = in.nextLine();
        Integer nr = in.nextInt();
        Integer verdiepingen = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        String post = in.nextLine();
        String stad = in.nextLine();
        Integer massa = in.nextInt();
        straat.addWoning(new Rijtjeshuis(straat, nr, verdiepingen, post, stad, massa));
}
```

}

Even so this only allows you add one single object, unless you modify your code to read and add in a loop